# Indirect navigation field with EF4

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm wondering if its possible to have a property/field in a class that is populated directly from a database. I know that directly implementing this would break design patterns, such as separation of concerns, but I'm hoping to have some configuration in the `OnModelCreating` function of my `DbContext`.

In the example below, given a `Product`, I'd like to find out on which `PriceTables` it appears:

```
public class PriceTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }

    public PriceTable()
    {
        Prices = new HashSet<Price>();
    }
}

public class Price
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int PriceTableID { get; set; }
    public virtual PriceTable PriceTable { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    // This is what I'd like to achieve
    /*
    public HashSet<PriceTable> PriceTables { 
        get {
            // and here, return something from the DB
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Just to clarify: my model is **not** like the one below, but it works on the same way (so that I need this separation of classes, with this "junction table").

AFAIK, using LINQ I could find the information I want with the following:

```
 from p in Prices
 where p.Product.ID == MY_PRODUCT_ID
 select p.PriceTable
```

Which means that is the query I'd like to embed in my `Product` class!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Is it possible?* Well, have you tried it?

Comment: It is possible but not recommended. Data Transfer Objects should not call the database, they should only be filled with data by some external query.

Comment: That means that, given an instance of PriceTable, if I'd like to know how much a Product would cost, in fact I'd have to search in the reverse order (i.e., search through a list of prices for the specific product)?

Comment: @Magnus based on your observation, that DTO should not call the database, where is the right place to manipulate different classes and queries from the DB? The DTO should not be aware of this, neither the Controller (otherwise I will not respet the DRY principle), and the repository should only look for one type of class. What's the best separation of concerns on this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished my objectives by changing the model to match the following (with changes described as comments):

```
public class PriceTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }

    // New field, which allows me to query "all the Products in some PriceTable"
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return Prices.Select(p => p.Product);
            }
        }

    public PriceTable()
    {
        Prices = new HashSet<Price>();
    }
}

public class Price
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int PriceTableID { get; set; }
    public virtual PriceTable PriceTable { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    // New field, previsouly automatically generated by EF4
    public HashSet<Price> Prices { get; set; } 

    // New field, which allows me to query "all the PriceTables on which a Product appears"
    public IEnumerable<PriceTable> PriceTables 
        {
            get 
            { 
                return Prices.Select(p => p.PriceTables); 
            } 
        }
}
```